# What could be the best way to bypass `MemoryError` in this case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, numexpr

I have two `numpy` arrays of pretty large size. First is `arr1` of size `(40, 40, 3580)` and second is `arr2` of size `(3580, 50)`. What I want to achieve is

```
arr_final = np.sum(arr1[..., None]*arr2, axis = 2)
```

such that the size of `arr_final` is just `(40, 40, 50)`. However, in doing the above, python probably caches internal array operations, so I keep on getting memory error. Is there any way so as to avoid internal caching and just have final result? I have looked at `numexpr`, but I am not sure how one can achieve `arr1[..., None]*arr2`, and then `sum` over `axis=2` in `numexpr`. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You are broadcasting a (40,40,3580,1) against (1,1,3580,50), producing (40,40,3580,50) array.  Then you'll sum, reducing that to (40,40,50).  But you still have to have spare to the big intermediate value.  You could try iterating on the size 50 dimension.  50 loops on a large task should be ok time wise.

Comment: This temporary array is big, but it should be like 2GB big, not `MemoryError` big. Unless your dtype is `object` (in which case: don't do that), or you're using 32-bit Python (dittp), or you're on an embedded platform (OK, that's a problem). It's still worth trying to optimize, but it's _also_ worth trying to figure out how you're running out of memory.

Comment: That kind of looks like it's just `dot`.

Comment: `arr1[:, None]*arr2` doesn't actually work. Did you mean `arr1[..., None]*arr2`?

Comment: @user2357112 yeah it is `arr1[..., None]*arr2`.

Comment: @abarnert Yes I'm using 32-bit Python

Comment: OK. Any reason you _need_ to use 32-bit Python? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant `np.sum(arr1[..., None]*arr2, axis = 2)`, with a `...` instead of a `:`, then that's just `dot`:

```
arr3 = arr1.dot(arr2)
```

This should be more efficient than explicitly materializing `arr1[..., None]*arr2`, but I don't know exactly what intermediates it allocates.

You can also express the computation with `einsum`. Again, this should be more efficient than explicitly materializing `arr1[..., None]*arr2`, but I don't know exactly what it allocates.

```
arr3 = numpy.einsum('ijk,kl', arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! I think the memory allocation is very efficient in this case.